# I have a json object that I obtained from drafter and I only want the schema

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using node to call drafter in order to generate the json schema for an application. My goal is to get rid of all the extra output that is spit out by drafter. I end up with a huge thing of json but I only need a small portion of it.

This is what is output:

```js
{
  "element": "parseResult",
  "content": [
    {
      "element": "category",
      "meta": {
        "classes": [
          "api"
        ],
        "title": "Test"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "meta": [
          {
            "element": "member",
            "meta": {
              "classes": [
                "user"
              ]
            },
            "content": {
              "key": {
                "element": "string",
                "content": "FORMAT"
              },
              "value": {
                "element": "string",
                "content": "1A"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "content": [
        {
          "element": "category",
          "meta": {
            "classes": [
              "resourceGroup"
            ],
            "title": "Questions"
          },
          "content": [
            {
              "element": "resource",
              "meta": {
                "title": "Questions"
              },
              "attributes": {
                "href": "/questions"
              },
              "content": [
                {
                  "element": "transition",
                  "meta": {
                    "title": "List All Questions"
                  },
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "element": "httpTransaction",
                      "content": [
                        {
                          "element": "httpRequest",
                          "attributes": {
                            "method": "GET"
                          },
                          "content": []
                        },
                        {
                          "element": "httpResponse",
                          "attributes": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "headers": {
                              "element": "httpHeaders",
                              "content": [
                                {
                                  "element": "member",
                                  "content": {
                                    "key": {
                                      "element": "string",
                                      "content": "Content-Type"
                                    },
                                    "value": {
                                      "element": "string",
                                      "content": "application/json"
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          "content": [
                            {
                              "element": "dataStructure",
                              "content": [
                                {
                                  "element": "Question List"
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "element": "asset",
                              "meta": {
                                "classes": [
                                  "messageBody"
                                ]
                              },
                              "attributes": {
                                "contentType": "application/json"
                              },
                              "content": "[\n  {\n    \"question\": \"Favourite programming language?\",\n    \"published_at\": \"2014-11-11T08:40:51.620Z\",\n    \"url\": \"/questions/1\",\n    \"choices\": [\n      {\n        \"choice\": \"Javascript\",\n        \"url\": \"/questions/1/choices/1\",\n        \"votes\": 2048\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n]"
                            },
                            {
                              "element": "asset",
                              "meta": {
                                "classes": [
                                  "messageBodySchema"
                                ]
                              },
                              "attributes": {
                                "contentType": "application/schema+json"
                              },
                              "content": "{\n  \"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\",\n  \"type\": \"array\"\n}"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "element": "resource",
              "meta": {
                "title": "Question"
              },
              "attributes": {
                "href": "/questions/{id}",
                "hrefVariables": {
                  "element": "hrefVariables",
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "id"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "number",
                          "content": 1234
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "content": [
                {
                  "element": "transition",
                  "meta": {
                    "title": "Retrieve Question"
                  },
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "element": "httpTransaction",
                      "content": [
                        {
                          "element": "httpRequest",
                          "attributes": {
                            "method": "GET"
                          },
                          "content": []
                        },
                        {
                          "element": "httpResponse",
                          "attributes": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "headers": {
                              "element": "httpHeaders",
                              "content": [
                                {
                                  "element": "member",
                                  "content": {
                                    "key": {
                                      "element": "string",
                                      "content": "Content-Type"
                                    },
                                    "value": {
                                      "element": "string",
                                      "content": "application/json"
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          "content": [
                            {
                              "element": "dataStructure",
                              "content": [
                                {
                                  "element": "Question"
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "element": "asset",
                              "meta": {
                                "classes": [
                                  "messageBody"
                                ]
                              },
                              "attributes": {
                                "contentType": "application/json"
                              },
                              "content": "{\n  \"question\": \"Favourite programming language?\",\n  \"published_at\": \"2014-11-11T08:40:51.620Z\",\n  \"url\": \"/questions/1\",\n  \"choices\": [\n    {\n      \"choice\": \"Javascript\",\n      \"url\": \"/questions/1/choices/1\",\n      \"votes\": 2048\n    }\n  ]\n}"
                            },
                            {
                              "element": "asset",
                              "meta": {
                                "classes": [
                                  "messageBodySchema"
                                ]
                              },
                              "attributes": {
                                "contentType": "application/schema+json"
                              },
                              "content": "{\n  \"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\",\n  \"type\": \"object\",\n  \"properties\": {\n    \"question\": {\n      \"type\": \"string\"\n    },\n    \"published_at\": {\n      \"type\": \"string\"\n    },\n    \"url\": {\n      \"type\": \"string\"\n    },\n    \"choices\": {\n      \"type\": \"array\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"required\": [\n    \"question\",\n    \"published_at\",\n    \"url\",\n    \"choices\"\n  ]\n}"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "element": "category",
          "meta": {
            "classes": [
              "dataStructures"
            ]
          },
          "content": [
            {
              "element": "dataStructure",
              "content": [
                {
                  "element": "object",
                  "meta": {
                    "id": "Question"
                  },
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "question"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "Favourite programming language?"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "published_at"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "2014-11-11T08:40:51.620Z"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "url"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "/questions/1"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "choices"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "array",
                          "content": [
                            {
                              "element": "Choice"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "element": "dataStructure",
              "content": [
                {
                  "element": "object",
                  "meta": {
                    "id": "Choice"
                  },
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "choice"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "Javascript"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "url"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "/questions/1/choices/1"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "votes"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "number",
                          "content": 2048
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "element": "dataStructure",
              "content": [
                {
                  "element": "array",
                  "meta": {
                    "id": "Question List"
                  },
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "element": "Question"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The bit below is what I need.

```
content = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "question": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "published_at": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "url": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "choices": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "question",
    "published_at",
    "url",
    "choices"
  ]
}
```

This is the code I have as of right now and it is not working the way I am envisioning. If you need any more information to help me please ask.

App.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var edit = require('string-editor');
var lodash = require('lodash');
var _ = require('underscore');
const util = require('util');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('drafter -f json test.apib' , function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    const json = JSON.parse(stdout);
    //console.log(json)
var res
function loopThrough(obj){
        for(var key in obj){
            if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
            if(typeof obj[key] !== 'object'){
                //if (cond) var x = {'$schema': };
                //if (_.hasIn(obj, '$schema')) {

                    res = res + "\n" + (key+" = "+obj[key]);
                //}
            } else {
                loopThrough(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }
    loopThrough(json);
    //parse = JSON.parse(test);
    //string = JSON.stringify(test, null,  '  ');
   //string = string.replace(/\\n/g, '');
    fs.writeFile('test.json', res, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
    });  
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }

});
```

This is the ouput I am down to.

```js
undefined
element = parseResult
element = category
0 = api
title = Test
element = member
0 = user
element = string
content = FORMAT
element = string
content = 1A
element = category
0 = resourceGroup
title = Questions
element = resource
title = Questions
href = /questions
element = transition
title = List All Questions
element = httpTransaction
element = httpRequest
method = GET
element = httpResponse
statusCode = 200
element = httpHeaders
element = member
element = string
content = Content-Type
element = string
content = application/json
element = dataStructure
element = Question List
element = asset
0 = messageBody
contentType = application/json
content = [
  {
    "question": "Favourite programming language?",
    "published_at": "2014-11-11T08:40:51.620Z",
    "url": "/questions/1",
    "choices": [
      {
        "choice": "Javascript",
        "url": "/questions/1/choices/1",
        "votes": 2048
      }
    ]
  }
]
element = asset
0 = messageBodySchema
contentType = application/schema+json
content = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array"
}
element = resource
title = Question
href = /questions/{id}
element = hrefVariables
element = member
0 = required
element = string
content = id
element = number
content = 1234
element = transition
title = Retrieve Question
element = httpTransaction
element = httpRequest
method = GET
element = httpResponse
statusCode = 200
element = httpHeaders
element = member
element = string
content = Content-Type
element = string
content = application/json
element = dataStructure
element = Question
element = asset
0 = messageBody
contentType = application/json
content = {
  "question": "Favourite programming language?",
  "published_at": "2014-11-11T08:40:51.620Z",
  "url": "/questions/1",
  "choices": [
    {
      "choice": "Javascript",
      "url": "/questions/1/choices/1",
      "votes": 2048
    }
  ]
}
element = asset
0 = messageBodySchema
contentType = application/schema+json
content = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "question": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "published_at": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "url": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "choices": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "question",
    "published_at",
    "url",
    "choices"
  ]
}
element = category
0 = dataStructures
element = dataStructure
element = object
id = Question
element = member
0 = required
element = string
content = question
element = string
content = Favourite programming language?
element = member
0 = required
element = string
content = published_at
element = string
content = 2014-11-11T08:40:51.620Z
element = member
0 = required
element = string
content = url
element = string
content = /questions/1
element = member
0 = required
element = string
content = choices
element = array
element = Choice
element = dataStructure
element = object
id = Choice
element = member
0 = required
element = string
content = choice
element = string
content = Javascript
element = member
0 = required
element = string
content = url
element = string
content = /questions/1/choices/1
element = member
0 = required
element = string
content = votes
element = number
content = 2048
element = dataStructure
element = array
id = Question List
element = Question
```

Comment: Do you want just output that is the same keys, but pointing to empty strings? Or, to be more precise, what exactly is the output you're wanting (what format do you want your schema in?) Or maybe you want it pointing to strings that correspond to the type of the expected value?

Comment: I just edited my question. @KyleBaker

Answer (score 1):

You could try running it through an online JSON schema generation tool like this: http://jsonschema.net/#/

You will also want to consider reading up on the proposed JSON Schema specification here: http://json-schema.org/documentation.html

**UPDATED:** If you would like to generate the schema at runtime via Node, you could leverage a module like [json-schema-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-generator).

**UPDATED AGAIN:** I am not sure I follow you but, from looking at your data, you should be able to use the following to grab all content with the `contentType` of `application/schema+json` like so:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var schemas = [];

function isSchemaType(contentItem) {
  return _.get(contentItem, 'attributes.contentType') == 'application/schema+json';
}

function parseContent(content) {
  if (_.isObject(content) && _.isArray(content.content)) {
    _.forEach(content.content, parseContent);
  } else if (isSchemaType(content)) {
    schemas.push(JSON.parse(content.content));
  }
}

parseContent(jsonData);

console.log(schemas);
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k7dcd6s2/

Comment: Yes I know I can do that I just would like to be able to do this all with in a node.js app. The schema is in there but I only want just that section of the json. I know how it should be formatted and everything, that is not my question. I just want to be able to go through the object in the app and take out the pieces I don't want.

Comment: you could use something like lodash (_.omit) to remove portions of the object. Perhaps I am missing the point.

Comment: If you needed to remove a nested object, you could use lodash's _.unset function.

Comment: I will take a look at that and let you know if it's what I'm thinking thank you

Comment: Let me know which solution works for you and I'll update my answer to reflect it.

Comment: I made changes to my question if you take a look that might help you understand what I am trying to do a little better, Thanks.

Comment: Part of your problem is that your JSON is not valid. The section that you are trying to grab contains quotes that should be escaped.

Comment: Think I have it in a lot easier manner I don't know if you know a way to reduce from what I have now I'm stuck where I am now.